# What's the best way to record webcam video and record into a signal file in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm developing a html application which only works in Chrome. I want to implement a video message recording and playing recorded videos.

I found a way to record each audio and video. But I couldn't record both audio and video into a single video file.
https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

I found Kurento, it looks useful. But because of its license, primitive javascript solutions are better if there are.
http://www.kurento.org/

Comment: There are tons of options. Do you want to connect to a server and record that way or just do the recording in the browser?

Comment: Probably I'm no licensing expert, but the license in Kurento (LGPLv2.1) is quite flexible. It will let you build solutions based on Kurento without releasing your code. Is there anything in particular that you find restrictive about the license?  Also, please note that Kurento is a *media server*, so if you are looking for a way to record **locally**, you are probably looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to record audio+video into (for example) a webm file.  See a Firefox MediaRecorder testcase: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/test/test_mediarecorder_record_gum_video_timeslice.html